# Tweepy error: must be unicode not str

Tags: python, unicode, tweepy

I am using a script to stream tweets using the tweedy module, by defining a stream listener.

```
import time
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import io

ckey="*****"
consumer_secret="*****"
access_token_key="*****"
access_token_secret="*****"

start_time = time.time() 
keyword_list = ['keyword'] 


class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):

        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.tweet_data = []

    def on_data(self, data):

        saveFile = io.open('raw_tweets.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8')

        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:

            try:

                self.tweet_data.append(data)

                return True


            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
                time.sleep(5)
                pass

        saveFile = io.open('raw_tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        saveFile.write(u'[\n')
        saveFile.write(','.join(self.tweet_data))
        saveFile.write(u'\n]')
        saveFile.close()
        exit()


    def on_error(self, status):

        print statuses

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, consumer_secret) #OAuth object
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)


twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener(start_time, time_limit=20)) 
twitterStream.filter(track=keyword_list, languages =['en'])
```

I get an error like this:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "search.py", line 61, in <module>
>     twitterStream.filter(track=keyword_list, languages =['en'])  
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py",
> ```
>
> line 430, in filter
>           self._start(async)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py",
>   line 346, in _start
>           self._run()
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py",
>   line 286, in _run
>           raise exception
>       TypeError: must be unicode, not str

I am trying to understand, but I cannot figure out..
Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: I moved to python 3 and it works. Have you find any other solution?